# Duplicate Hygiene tag

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[In the page 4 of the `tags` page](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tags?page=4&tab=popular), the 'hygiene' tags are redundant, the difference is a typo.

It's possible remove or merge this redundant tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hygiene/hygeine tags were both synonyms of [personal-care], so I removed the (misspelled) synonym which should remove it from the tag listing shortly.

Comment: If the typo version is used on a post again, I would recommend adding the synonym again to keep everything where it belongs.'

Comment: I tried burning this tag some time ago, but was told is was there because it was such a common misspelling that it deservered being a synonym...